# How do I customize the notification banner in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: notifications

Is there anyway to move the notification center alert/banner to bottom right instead of top right?

Comment: Probably not. I didn't find anything by [running strings on frameworks](http://superuser.com/questions/455755/how-to-explore-more-defaults-write-tweaks-on-os-x).

Comment: I'd like to resize the banner. It is too small for the messages of one of my applications...